# Pyspark schema: how to check nullability?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am attempting to compare two pyspark schemas. However, I want to be able to see which columns do not match exactly. Therefore, I don't want to use simple `schema1 == schema2`. However, I don't see a way to compare fields for nullability. Is that possible?

```
def assert_schemas_equal(schema1, schema2):
  mismatches_counter = 0
  for field1, field2 in zip(schema1, schema2):
    if field1.name != field2.name or field1.dataType != field2.dataType:
      print('Mismatch!', field1, field2)
      mismatches_counter += 1
  if mismatches_counter>0:
    return False
  else:
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `nullable` property.

```py
def assert_schemas_equal(schema1, schema2):
  mismatches_counter = 0
  for field1, field2 in zip(schema1, schema2):
    if field1.name != field2.name or field1.dataType != field2.dataType or field1.nullable != field2.nullable:
      print('Mismatch!', field1, field2)
      mismatches_counter += 1
  if mismatches_counter>0:
    return False
  else:
    return True
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @Grevioos Did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this one will do the work

```
set(df1.schema).symmetric_difference(set(df2.schema))
```